# Correct jQuery Syntax for accessing text of array in one line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access the text of the first "th" element of the first element of "rows" with jQuery and would like to do so in one line

```
var currentStation = $(rows[0]).find("th")[0].text();
```

What would be the correct syntax to do so? 
I am able to get the "th" element, but as soon as I try to access the text I get error messages.
I already tried numerous variations of different brackets combinations, but each one threw me errors.

Comment: show your `html`?

Comment: It's beecause you're using `[0]` at the end - this accesses the element, not the jQuery object, which is why `.text()` will no longer work as that's for jQuery only. Replacing `.text()` with `.innerText` should work.

Comment: please provide details code

Comment: what's wrong with `var text = rows[0].cells[0].innerText;` ?

Comment: and show the error messages

Comment: @Kaushik why?  What would that show that hasn't been described?

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz: Nothing! I just didn't know about the function yet. Thanks very much. That was really helpful!

Comment: @user7290573 Thanks! I think that boils down to the exact problem I had so far working with jQuery. I have neve made a clear distinction between jQuery objects and elements. You helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: @freedomn-m showing html can give him multiple options. Like access with class? or just with tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your `[0]` on `find("th")` takes the HTML element out of the jQuery object. The easiest way to do this is to either use `innerText` instead of `text`:

```
var currentStation = $(rows[0]).find("th")[0].innerText;
```

Or don't use `[0]`, rather `first`:

```
var currentStation = $(rows[0]).find("th:first").text();
```

(Or another `first`):

```
var currentStation = $(rows[0]).find("th").first().text();
```

Comment: Yes, was just about to add that @freedomn-m :p

Comment: Or yet another: `.eq(0)`

Answer (score 1):

`text()` is a method on jQuery objects.

You are extracting the DOM element object from the jQuery object and then trying to call `text()` on the DOM element object.

Use the [`:first` selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) instead (note this is a jQuery selector and not a CSS selector)

```
const $firstRow = $(rows[0]);
const $firstTh = $firstRow.find("th:first");
var currentStation = $firstTh.text();
```